# Displaying data from mySQL database to vue.js front end using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js

i am currently trying to display data from mySQL database on xampp on my vue.js template using php. I found a tutorial online on how to do so, but after putting the code, the data is not displayed nor do i get any errors in my console, so i am not able to debug the reason for it not working. Could someone help me out?

**Index.php**

```
<?php

//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
$received_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data = array();
if($received_data->action == 'fetchall')
{
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM tbl_sample 
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}

if($received_data->action == 'fetchSingle')
{
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM tbl_sample 
        WHERE id = '".$received_data->id."'
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $data['id'] = $row['id'];
        $data['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $data['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

I am calling it in my dashboard.vue page like so

**dashboard.vue**

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="row in allData" :key="row">
    <td>{{ row.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.last_name }}</td>
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        name="edit"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit"
        @click="fetchData(row.id)"
      >Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        name="delete"
        class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"
        @click="deleteData(row.id)"
      >Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

export default {
  metaInfo: {
    // if no subcomponents specify a metaInfo.title, this title will be used
    title: "Dashboard v1",
    mixins: [clickaway]
  },
  components: {
    Notebook,
    Page,
    highcharts: Chart,
    CustomPie,
    CustomGuage,
    CommitChart
 },
 data() {
   return {
     allData: "",
     myModel: false,
     actionButton: "Insert",
     dynamicTitle: "Add Data",
 },

  mounted() {
    this.testQuery();
    this.getContacts();

  },

  methods: {
    fetchAllData: function() {
      axios
        .post("index.php", {
          action: "fetchall"
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          application.allData = response.data;
          console.log(response.data)
        });
    },
openModel: function() {
  application.first_name = "";
  application.last_name = "";
  application.actionButton = "Insert";
  application.dynamicTitle = "Add Data";
  application.myModel = true;
},

fetchData: function(id) {
  axios
    .post("index.php", {
      action: "fetchSingle",
      id: id
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      application.first_name = response.data.first_name;
      application.last_name = response.data.last_name;
      application.hiddenId = response.data.id;
      application.myModel = true;
      application.actionButton = "Update";
      application.dynamicTitle = "Edit Data";
    });
},

created: function() {
  this.fetchAllData();
},

};
```

mySQL database looks like this -
[image]

I dont know much about php or databases, could someone tell me where i am going wrong. i have put the correct database name and details and have also installed axios in my template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you could be running into a few issues at the same time. I would suggest first testing independently to validate the PHP code works fine on your local. Via browser with *http://localhost/index.php?action=fetch-all* depending on where is located in your project in order to see if you are communicating with the database. I've adapted the code a little to see results via GET.

```
<?php
//index.php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
$received_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$result = [];

if ($received_data->action === 'fetch-all' || $_GET['action'] === 'fetch-all') {

  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM tbl_sample
            ORDER BY id DESC";

  $statement = $connect->query($query);

  while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

The response in the browser should look like:

```
[{"id":"3","first_name":"Donna","last_name":"Huber"},{"id":"2","first_name":"Peter","last_name":"Parker"},{"id":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}]
```

I've noticed some missing braces, not sure if you have working some Linting on vue...
After that, update the fecthAllData function:

```
methods: {    
    fetchAllData: function () {
        axios
          .get("index.php" + '?action=fetch-all')
          .then((response) => {
                this.allData = response.data;
                console.log('response', this.allData);
          });
      }, ...
```

In case you don't see any results yet, check the network tab in your browser, you should be able to see the route call was triggered when the page loads. Hope my words helped.

**Update - PHP Build-in WebServer approach:**

The solution above should work from the default's webserver port (80). In case of using PHP build-in web server, would be required to do some proxying for API calls from Vue.js.

See if you have installed Vue.cli (for details check https://cli.vuejs.org/ & https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#proxycontext-config).

After proper installation, in order to move API calls to a different port from your Vue.js app to where the PHP code is served, add the following lines in the proxy config:

```
proxy: {
    "/api": "http://[::1]:8090"
}
```

Axios call would also need to be updated like:

```
.get("api" + '?action=fetch-all')
```

The api urls (`/api`) calls would be redirected to port `8090` (I've used port 8090 since I'm not sure which ports are currently occupied in your local machine).

At this point, you can retry accessing http://localhost:8090/?action=fetch-all from your browser (after serving the application `php -S localhost:8090`), and from Vue.js app getting the same results.

Comment: Hey so i edited the php file, used a different query and table,  and ran it on xampp server and i get the response in the browser,thanks for that,  but in the browser console in vue.js, i get the error ' xhr.js?b50d:178 GET http://localhost:81/contacts.php?action=fetch-all 404 (Not Found)"  and then "Error: Request failed with status code 404". Could you tell me where i went wrong? I appreciate the help because i have been stuck for a while

Comment: In the network tab too i see the error 404 not found, is it something to do with the location of the file in my project? I ran the php file on localhost:8080 by running this command in the terminal from my project folder 'php -S localhost:8080' , checked in the browser the result was there

Comment: Well, the solution was developed for localhost over port `80`, then trying to access it over port `8080` makes the difference. For the **PHP build-in server**, I've added another approach above that actually matches what you trying to accomplish. Hope it suits your needs :)